# Bunyan stdout truncated

Tags: node.js, bunyan

I have Bunyan logger writing to both a file and stdout.  However, before the logger can finish writing everything to stdout, the node process exists and the logs to stdout are truncated.

Is there anyway to wait for the logs to finish printing before exiting fully?

Answer (score 0):

Some where in your node code you might have used process.exit() due to which the process exists before doing the work which runs on a different process thread(i.e. I/O) or which take time. So if you've used something like that, you can set a few seconds timeout for that, so that all other tasks are done before exit.

Comment: Is there a better way than just waiting an arbitrary time?  I am using `process.exit` for some cleaning up at the end.

Comment: That should actually say I am *not* using `process.exit`

Comment: try to do the cleanup after a few seconds of wait... I guess you wan't to kill the process as its not getting killed automatically... Is it so?

Comment: No.  Node is exiting before bunyan can finish writing out everything it's logging to stdout.

Comment: yaa... thats why use some seconds delay... my question was whether your process is exiting normally or not without using process.exit?

Comment: I gotcha.  It exits normally without process.exit.